# Parsing Military time is not working for times form 1200 to 1259

Tags: java, date

I am trying to convert military time to date, it works good except when time ranges from 1200 to 12:59.  The expected times be 12:MM instead of 00:MM.

```
String format = String.format("%04d", Integer.parseInt(milTime));
date = new SimpleDateFormat("hhmm").parse(format);
```

Here's some examples:-

```
1)milTime:1245  <--- Input
Date: Thu Jan 01 00:45:00 EST 1970   //Expecting Thu Jan 01 12:45:00 EST 1970

2)milTime:1200
Date:Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 1970    //Expecting Thu Jan 01 12:00:00 EST 1970
```

Comment: use `HHmm` instead of `hhmm`

Comment: I think you are confusing 24 hour clock time with standard 12 hour time where 12:00 on a 24 hour clock is 12 noon and 00:00 is 12 midnight.

Comment: Off topic, why are you using the outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class? I warmly recommend the modern `DateTimeFormatter` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `"HHmm"` as a date format specifier instead of `"hhmm"` - according to [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), `H` is used for a zero-based 24-hour-format while `h` is used for 1-based 12-hour format.

Comment: That is the solution indeed. Would be good if you could also say why